# Is it possible to run a Java EE backend with persistent H2 in EC2?

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, amazon-ec2, h2

I want to run an Java EE application which uses Hibernate and a H2 database in the cloud, e.g. in EC2. The application offers a REST interface and modifys the (currently in local develop mode) in memory H2 database.

Is it possible to deploy the application in EC2 (e.g. with Tomcat server) with a H2 database in file mode, so that the database will not reset during restart of the server and persist the data?

Comment: Yes it is possible,EC2 is as like any normal computer

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So I just have to set H2 to file mode and it will persist the data in the database even if I restart the server?

Comment: As @MeladEzzat indicated, an EC2 server is just another computer.  One warning - if you use `Instance Storage` for your instance and you then stop and restart the instance, the data on that disk will be gone.  Use EBS storage for the database to persist across stop/start events.

Comment: Don't know if you need this but, be warned, H2 flushes data to disk with 1 second intervals or when jvm gets a kill signal. So, if you have a hard consistency requirements, be sure jvm and/or OS restarts properly, otherwise you might lose some data(last 1 second + time to flush data to disk) or endup with a corrupt database.